# Uploading video with carrierwave-video an error : "Video Failed to transcode with FFmpeg."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

I have already added new column to microposts as video. And now I want to use carrierwave-video gem (https://github.com/rheaton/carrierwave-video). Now when I tried to upload video I have an error. (I have tried to upload video in .MOV format)

**Error**

```
Video Failed to transcode with FFmpeg. Check ffmpeg install and verify video is not corrupt or cut short. Original error: undefined method `set_success' for #<Micropost:0x007fbf0d40dd68>
```

**video_uploader.rb**

```
class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::Video

  process encode_video: [:mp4, callbacks: { after_transcode: :set_success } ]
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

**Gemfile**

```
 gem 'carrierwave',             '0.10.0'
 gem 'carrierwave-video'
```

**micropost Model**

```
 mount_uploader :video, VideoUploader
```

I have also made configurations in my FFmpeg file with a file download from FFmpeg.

```
 Taner-MacBook-Pro:~ tanerkoroglu$  /Users/tanerkoroglu/Downloads/SnowLeopard_Lion_Mountain_Lion_Mavericks_12.12.2015/ffmpeg ; exit;
 ffmpeg version 2.8.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with llvm-gcc 4.2.1 (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
  configuration: --prefix=/Volumes/Ramdisk/sw --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-libspeex --enable-libvpx --disable-decoder=libvpx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-avfilter --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-filters --enable-libgsm --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx265 --disable-doc --arch=x86_64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
 Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
   usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

  Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
   logout
   Saving session...
    ...copying shared history...
     ...saving history...truncating history files...
      ...completed.
    Deleting expired sessions...146 completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `gem 'carrierwave-ffmpeg'` to your Gemfile and be sure, that you install `ffmpeg` and `ffmpeg2theora` via [homebrew](http://brew.sh) on your computer.